# Correct installation of postgresql and postgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, mac, server

Goodmorning everybody! I'm new in this forum and I hope you would help me in solving my problem. I'm practicing the use of Qgis and i need to setup postgresql and postgis on my mac yosemite 10.10. Does anybody of you have a correct step-to-step guide which shows how to setup correctly that kind of local server?

Comment: http://postgis.net/install/ Postgres.app, appears to be the recommended way. http://postgresapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are packages created for MacOS, usually by KingChaos. Looks like you can also use homebrew:

- http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres
- http://brew.sh/

As usual, the best way is to look at the docs, as already said by John, check this link:

- http://postgis.net/install